# ASP.NET Fails to Load CSS and Javascript Files

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm experiencing a very peculiar issue with ASP.NET.
I have a small website. I've written a simple MasterPage that is used across most of the site's pages.

I want to include Bootstrap and jQuery's CSS and Javascript files. When I link then in my master page with URI pointing at remote location (see below), everything works fine:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Stylesheets" runat="server">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

For couple of reasons I want these JS and CSS files to be available locally, so I downloaded the relevant files to the server. But when I try to include these local files in the master page, they fail to load.

I tried:

- Using absolute paths (i.e. `~/res/css/...`)
- Using `<%= ResolveUrl("...") %>`
- Using `<ScriptManager>` - identical effect
- When trying to include these files in the same way in the `head` `contentPlaceHolder` in the content pages, the effect is the same.

Example of non-working code:

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Stylesheets" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/App_LocalResources/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="~/App_LocalResources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/App_LocalResources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

The result is the same whether I use the `ContentPlaceHolder` or not.

If you could assist me in resolving this issue, I'd be genuinely awesome - thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want it locally you shloudn´t use a CDN. You can download the files and put it on a script folder.

Comment: Of course. I see that I wansn't 100% clear in the question - I downloaded all the relevant files to `~/res/css/` and `~/res/js/` respectively.

Comment: Have you inspected the error you get in the browser inspector? I bet you could figure out your error if you inspected what the URL's are being resolved to and why they are not correct.

Comment: Are you seeing a 404 for these files in the browser?

Comment: Note that there is no way to help if you show only correctly working code... Code/HTML that does not work the way you want would make the question much better...

Comment: @autin wernli Yes, I have already checked for errors before asking but after you mentioned it I noticed I forgot to turn Logging on on Firebug's console. So yeah, I do get `404`s - the URLs are no being constructed correctly, although I **am** using the `~` operator. (they are relative, somehow).
@Alexei Levenkov - I'm on it, hold on.

Comment: Even after I amanded the URLs to relative, I still get `404`s. I'm suspecting it has something to do with the `Web.Config` since the URLs are right this time.

Comment: What does your rendered HTML show for the resource paths? Try using `src='<%# ResolveUrl("~/your_path_here...")%>'` and in your master page code-behind call `Page.Header.DataBind()`.

Comment: Thanks for update and very detailed self-answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to detect and resolve the cause of this issue failry quickly after reading through some very helpful comments - so kudos for the users who posted them.

The issue was being caused by `404`s (when trying to acces the `js` and `css` files). The `404`s happened due to:

- The URLs were not correct - although I used the `~` (home) character it somehow was converted to a path relative to the page.

Example of such `404` as seen in Firefox/Firebug Console (make sure that "Logging" is on:
[image: 404 in Firefox Consol]

I was able to resolve this issue by using `ResolveUrl`.
Example:
`<script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/App_LocalResources/js/bootstrap.min.js") %>"></script>`

- After resolving this first issue, the `404`s persisted.

  I tried to access the files directly through the browser, and I got a `IIS 404.8` error - meaning that the server was blocking access to the `App_LocalResources` folder. This is the default behaviour of IIS server on some predefined folder names (including `App_LocalResources`, `bin`, `App_Data`, etc.).

[image: IIS Server 404.8 Error Page]

So, I moved the `css` and `js` files to a folder named `res` and that did the trick.

**Eventually**, the `<head>` section in the master page looks like this:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Stylesheets" runat="server">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/res/css/bootstrap.min.css") %>" />
        <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/res/js/jquery.min.js") %>"></script>
        <script src="<%= ResolveUrl("~/res/js/bootstrap.min.js") %>"></script>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder> 
</head>
```